# same count array code, giving different resuls

Tags: php, soap, multidimensional-array

I am having difficulty understanding why the array count outputs results that dont make any sense.  I have the following code to count array items

```
echo $arrayLength = count($result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'])
```

Now, when the array contains the following:

```
Array ( 
        [caseNumber] => CAS-00477-Z7Z9N6 
        [dateCreated] => 18-02-2016 21:58
        [faultType] => Cable theft notification 
        [status] => Open [lastStatusChange] => Un-known 
       )
```

I get a count result of 5 for the above array
But for the following array I get a count of 2:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [caseNumber] => CAS-00475-H3Z4W4 
                       [dateCreated] => 18-02-2016 21:22 
                       [faultType] => Electricity outage - Business
                       [status] => Open 
                       [lastStatusChange] => Un-known 
                     ) 

        [1] => Array ( [caseNumber] => CAS-00476-F2N7H4 
                       [dateCreated] => 18-02-2016 21:22 
                       [faultType] => Electricity outage - Business 
                       [status] => Open 
                       [lastStatusChange] => Un-known ) 
                     )
```

I realised that when there are more than 1 items, the array displays differently from when are two or more items. Is there a way I can standardize the count ?

Both Array results comes from a SOAP API result set

Comment: What are you expecting 10 or 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` returns the number of items in the top level array, so the behavior you are seeing is correct.

It seems like the underlying problem is that you're dealing with is that when there are multiple results you get an array of results. If there is a single result you just get that result.

You can test for this by checking if a particular key is set:

```
if(isset($result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory']['caseNumber'])) {
    // Single result
} else {
    // Multiple results
}
```

You can also normalize the response so you can deal with it the same way regardless of whether or not their are multiple results:

```
if(isset($result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory']['caseNumber'])) {
    $result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'] = [ $result['GetRecentCasesResult']['CaseHistory'] ];
}
```

The above will ensure that you always have an array of results.

Answer (score 0):

Your second result is counting the outer array, the array of arrays so to speak.

Iterate over the array and count the value array each time. Need an example?

```
foreach ($secondExample as $key => $valueArray)
      echo count($valueArray) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `count` just count items in array.

Here - you have 5 items:

```
Array ( 
    [caseNumber] => CAS-00477-Z7Z9N6           // 1st
    [dateCreated] => 18-02-2016 21:58          // 2bd
    [faultType] => Cable theft notification    // 3rd
    [status] => Open                           // 4th
    [lastStatusChange] => Un-known             // 5th
)
```

And here - only two:

```
Array ( 
    // FIRST
    [0] => Array ( [caseNumber] => CAS-00475-H3Z4W4 
                   [dateCreated] => 18-02-2016 21:22 
                   [faultType] => Electricity outage - Business
                   [status] => Open 
                   [lastStatusChange] => Un-known 
                 ) 
    // SECOND
    [1] => Array ( [caseNumber] => CAS-00476-F2N7H4 
                   [dateCreated] => 18-02-2016 21:22 
                   [faultType] => Electricity outage - Business 
                   [status] => Open 
                   [lastStatusChange] => Un-known ) 
                 )
)
```

Normally, `count` doesn't count items in subarrays, but you can pass `1` (or `COUNT_RECURSIVE`) as second parameter to `count` and get `12` as a result for a second array.

So you can solve your problem either by checking if there's a `caseNumber` key for example in your array. If not - you should iterate over subarrays.
Or, you can `count` items with second parameter and without it. It values are different - again you should iterate over subarrays.

But the **most proper** solution - is to fix SOAP provider (if you can) so it will always return array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I Will also liaise with the SOAP provider